# How to read two byte register address using arduino wire library

Tags: i2c

I want to read a register 0x012A from the device I2C address 0x0A, the value stored in the register is two bytes, If the register address is one byte i can use Wire.requestFrom and give the register address and how many bytes i want to read since here register address itself 2 bytes i'am bit confused . can any one help in this regard.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/rodan/ds3231/blob/master/ds3231.cpp#L409-L413 . As far as I can see. You begin a transmition to the device; you write your two registry address bytes; then close the transmission. After that you use `requestFrom` to read any number of bytes (which happens to be two as well, in your case).

Answer (score 3):

> i can use Wire.requestFrom and give the register address and how many bytes i want to read

So you give it `2` to ask for 2 bytes.

Then you combine them. How you do that depends on what the bytes represent.  If the first is the upper byte and the second the lower byte of a 16 bit value then you would:

```cpp
uint8_t b1 = Wire.read();
uint8_t b2 = Wire.read();

uint16_t val = (b1 << 8) | b2;
```

If it's the other way around then just swap the variables in the combining section.

However if the values are some other arrangement (I saw something recently that had two registers with a 12 bit value with overlapping bits) you will have to combine it in the way that is required for that specific arrangement.